# Creating methods that allow bang and non-bang options

Tags: ruby, methods

I was wondering if it were possible to create a single method, say `Array#square` (which squares the elements in an array), that allows an optional bang `!` identifier?

This way, whether the receiver is permanently modified depends only on whether the method was called with a bang. For instance, can one define a method along the lines of:

```
class Array
  def square(!)
    #code
  end
end
```

Or, is it necessary to create two such methods?

```
class Array
  def square
    #code
  end
  def square!
    #code
  end
end
```

Comment: Your example doesn't reflect any sense. #sum is no way would modify the array. Thus #sum! is pointless.

Comment: You have to create two methods. The `!` is part of the method name, and can not be a parameter.

Comment: I apologize for the poor example. Squaring the elements in the array would have been a better choice as an example. I'll try editing the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convention to define two methods seperately, where the non dangerous version calls the bang method on a duplicate:

```
class Array
  def square
    dup.square!
  end
  def square!
    #code
  end
end
```

Comment: Who downvoted the correct answer? Admit yourself or face my wrath.

Comment: Who downvoted? Someone who just got the ability to downvote and wanted to exercise their new-found power. I added a +1 out of spite and because it's a good answer.